# Thermodynamics - $dU = C_v dT$

Tags: thermodynamics

Why in thermodynamics is $dU = C_v dT$ and not $dU = C_p dT$?

I don't need to know a formal proof-type explanation, so any general hand-waivey stuff that will help me build an intuitive feel for this will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $C_v$ and $C_p$, respectively?

Comment: @ACuriousMind $C_v$ is the heat capacity at constant volume per mole and $C_p$ is the heat capacity at constant pressure per mole.

Comment: It follows from $\Delta U_{AB} = Q_{AB} + W_{AB}$, $\Delta U_{AB}$ do not depend on the specific path from $A$ to $B$, you can thus follow an constant volume transformation and then a constant temperature transformation (or the other way around). On the former, $Q=C_v \Delta T$ and $W=0$ and on the latter $\Delta U=0$. Overall $\Delta U_{AB}=C_v \Delta T$. If you trade the constant volume transformation for a constant pressure one, you lose $W=0$.

Comment: @Tony thanks, also what is the difference between $C_v$ and $C_p$ and the 'specific heat capacity'?

Comment: From wikipedia: "Heat capacity is a measurable physical quantity equal to the ratio of the heat added to (or removed from) an object to the resulting temperature change.". For a gas it is not well defined, if the heat is added at constant volume, it is $C_v$, on the other hand if the heat is added at constant pressure it is $C_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_v$ is ***defined*** as $$C_v=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V$$ and $C_p$ is ***defined*** as $$C_p=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$$
It's nothing more and nothing less than that.

Answer (score -1):

As you know, heat capacity is defined as the heat required to raise the temperature by 1 degree (either Celsius or Kelvin).

From the first law of thermodynamics,
$\Delta U=\Delta q-P\Delta V$

So, at constant volume, $\Delta U=\Delta q$

According to the definition of specific heat,

$C_v=\frac{\Delta{q}}{\Delta {T}}=\frac{\Delta {U}}{\Delta {T}}$

So, at constant volume, you will need $C_v$ amount of heat to raise the temperature of the system under observation by $1$ degree.